# data structure for match many sets

Tags: data-structures

I have many files and calculate md5 line by line, and save all the md5 in database, now I get a new file and calculate md5 line by line, how I can find if any file match the new file with defined percent similarity, ex 90%, and get the matched file. what data structure should I use for space and time efficiency?

Comment: why do you calc md5 line by line?

Comment: do you want a data structure that just tells you what percent match a file is of another file? if so, how you define match?

Comment: I want to match a file of different version, if 90% line md5 of a file, can be found in another file, I define it matched.

Comment: You don't have to calc md5. You can just build a set of lines in each file. Check if overlap of the sets is 90%. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have many files to match, can't store all files in the memory.